Why does mapbox map zoom not work in safari using mouse wheel?
Why does mapbox map zoom not work in safari using mouse wheel? Also can't find information about similar problem on internet
// I tried many things like:

map.scrollZoom.enable();

//or

map.on('wheel', function(e) {
    if (!e.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        map.scrollZoom.disable();
    } else {
        map.scrollZoom.enable();
    }
});

